# Randomization Order in Systemverilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
class data_s;
  int c=5;
endclass

class config_c;
  data_s format[];
  rand int num_supp = 5;

  function new();
    format = new[num_supp];
    foreach(format[i])
      format[i] = new();
  endfunction
endclass

class packet;
  rand int nsid;
  rand int a;
  rand int b;  
endclass

  program p;
     packet p = new;
     config_c conf = new;

     initial begin
       p.randomize() with {nsid < (conf.num.supp + 1);
                      nsid > 0;
                      if(a < conf.format[nsid - 1].c)
                        b=0;
                      else
                        b=1;
                     } 
     end
 endprogram
```

In this code, I am getting a fatal error because `nsid` is not in the range of `num_supp`.  Therefore, in the if condition, it tries to access an object which is not created (like `format[32'hb235_44d5]`).

`solve nsid before b` is also not working.

I can use that if condition outside of the `randomize` function and it may work, but what can be the solution of this problem in the `randomize` function?

Comment: Still have lots of errors. Have you looked at my answer and compared the differences?

Comment: @dave_59: Yes, I have found the errors. But more important, I have got my answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem SystemVerilog does not allow you to use an expression with a random variable as an index to an array. You need to put your constraint in terms of a **foreach** loop. Also - a **solve before** directive does not change the solution space, just the distribution of values selected as solutions.

```
class data_s;
  bit [31:0] c=5;
endclass

class Config;
  data_s format[];
  rand int num_supp = 5;

  function new();
    format = new[num_supp];
    foreach(format[i])
      format[i] = new();
  endfunction
endclass

class packet;
  rand bit [31:0] nsid;
  rand bit [31:0] a,b;
endclass

module top;

   packet p = new;

   // Some other stuff
Config conf=new();
initial begin
  p.randomize() with {nsid < (conf.num_supp + 1);
                      foreach (conf.format[i])
              i == (nsid -1) ->
                      if(a < conf.format[i].c)
                        b==0;
                      else
                        b==1;
                      };
   $display("%p",p);
   end

endmodule
```